# Rotate the content of a MKMapView

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.1

I need to rotate the content of the mapView according to the compass value:

```
float myHeadingValue = newHeading.trueHeading;
```

and for rotating the map I use this:

```
[mapView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( [self degreesToRadians:myHeadingValue] )];
```

but it rotates the view, not the content of the view.

How can I make it to rotate the content, not the whole view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it creating in Interface Builder a smaller UIView and putting the MKMapView into it. The new UIView does not show the leftover map.

Comment: I loved this!  I did this too...except.  REMEMBER to set the view you are containing the MKMapView into as "Clip Subviews" if the containing view is not full screen.

Answer (score 5):

There may be an issue with the google logo being out of shot doing this though. Apple have contacted me to say that my app contravened the guidelines because the google logo was invisible.