# Rotate MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rotate the content of a MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551282/rotate-the-content-of-a-mkmapview)

I was wondering if there is a way to rotate a MKMapView. By default north is locked up and south down, is there a way to unlock this and allow the user to turn the angle of the map with two fingers? Is there a way to programatically change the angle of the map?